# Django-admin one of the field must be filled in django-models

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Hello I have model like

```
class mymodel(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    b = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    c = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=255)
```

Since I'm using the django admin as a back-end controller of the data stored in my model I want to make either one of them to not be null

for example the user must either fill `a` or either fill `b` or `both` to be filled, but if `both` are empty must throw an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add [custom](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#id1) validation like this

```
class mymodel(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    b = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    c = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=255)

    def clean(self):
        if not (self.a and self.b):
            raise ValidationError(....)
```